# Implement this simple logic in Prolog

Tags: prolog

How do I implement these simple statements in Prolog?

1. A (generic) number is even XOR a (generic) number is odd.
2. x is a not even number.

Then, if I query "x is odd", I should get true.

Please add some explanation, as I am finding Prolog surprisingly difficult.

**Note:** I am using [swish.swi-prolog.org](http://swish.swi-prolog.org)

**EDIT:**
I tried the following, but it's gives some error:

```
number(x).                          /*x is a number*/
odd(K) :- number(K) ; not(even(K)). /*if a number is not even => is odd*/
even(K) :- number(K) ; not(odd(K)). /*if a number is not odd => is even*/
not(odd(x)).                        /*x is not odd*/

?-even(x). /*Gives No permission to modify static procedure `number/1'*/
```

Formally, how would it be the right procedure?

Comment: Can you please add more explanation of what you're wanting? Can you provide any code? At least the query you're trying to run, what input, and what output you expect?

Comment: I edited with some code, as you requested. The logic statements that I want to implement are above. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you want Forward Chaining [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_chaining). See: [Forward Chaining](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~fp/courses/lp/lectures/21-forward.pdf) by "Frank Pfenning" and for SWI-Prolog see [Pfc](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=pfc) -- a package for forward chaining in Prolog, which will require you to install SWI-Prolog to use. Also read this related [thread](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/pfc-pack-forward-chaining-cant-get-to-work/2662) on Pfc. HTH

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined your predicates for `odd` and `even` is weird. You were saying a `variable(X)` is even if it is a number or it is not odd. And, you were saying a `variable(X)` is odd if it is a number or it is not even. By that logic your were saying that any number is always even and odd, and any non-number would have caused a stack overflow error.

Also, the reason for the error "No permission to modify static procedure 'number/1'" is because there is already a built-in predicate for determining if an parameter is a number. It's simply `number(X)`.

There's also a predicate for performing an integer divide with a remainder. For example:

```
?- divmod(42,5,X,Y).
X = 8,
Y = 2.
```

So, for this example, it's saying that `8 x 5 + 2 = 42`.

We can use that to determine `even` and `odd`.

```
even(X) :- number(X),divmod(X,2,_,0).
odd(X) :- number(X),divmod(X,2,_,1).
```

A number is even when divided by `2` it has a remainder of `0` and odd if the remainder is `1`.

Rather than define `odd(X) :- not(even(X))`, I defined both predicates as it is better, generally, to define predicates positively rather than by negation as the expected behaviour can be affected. It doesn't matter in this case, but in general it's a good habit to get in to.